# Soundcloud API How do I use on finish event

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, events, soundcloud

What is the correct usage of the Soundcloud API's stream finish event. I'm able to resolve a URL, start a stream, and detect when the song ends, but after the first song finishes the next streams are added to the first stream object. After the first song plays in my example, clicking stop causes the console.log("Stop Clicked: " Stream.ID) to fire for the previous streams too.

How do I get back out of the Track function to tell a new song to start rather than starting a new stream on a stream?

[Link to a Codepen of the below code](http://codepen.io/NewHighScore/pen/BKwJvo?editors=1011)

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '72e56a72d70b611ec8bcab7b2faf1015'
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    var urlid = ["https://soundcloud.com/sheckylovejoy/sad-trombone", "https://soundcloud.com/xcollective/x002"];
    $.get(
        'https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + urlid[0] + '&client_id=72e56a72d70b611ec8bcab7b2faf1015', 
         function (result) {
             $(document).trigger('Rotation/currentTrack', result);
             return result;
         });

    $(document).on('Track/finish', function(result){
        $.get(
            'https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + urlid[1] + '&client_id=72e56a72d70b611ec8bcab7b2faf1015', 
            function (result) {
                $(document).trigger('Rotation/currentTrack', result);
                console.log("Song 2 " + result.id);
                return result;
            });       
        });        
    });

    $(document).on('Rotation/currentTrack', function( e, results){
        console.log("results " + results.id + " " + results.title);
        track(e, results.id);
    });

    function track(e, trackNum){
    SC.stream('/tracks/' + trackNum).then(function(sound) {
        sound.play();
        $('#start').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("START Clicked")
            sound.play();
            sound.on('finish', function(){
                console.log("The track finished");
                $(document).trigger('Track/finish', sound);
            });
        });
    $('#stop').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Stop clicked: " + trackNum)
        sound.pause();
    });
    $('#skip').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sound.seek(170000);
    });

  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I am calling the methods on sound after multiple streams have been added to SC. I have found that I can store each sound to an Array then call the methods on the appropriate sound in the array. Also, storing sound on the SC object allows for the methods to be called outside of track().